# Switch between two installs of one program

Tags: which

I have two copies of `svn` on my machine.

1. `/usr/local/bin/svn`
2. `/opt/subversion/bin`

When I run `which svn` it states the first is running how can I switch it to the second?

Comment: Igniacio's answer will work, but I have to ask - WHY do you have two different versions of svn installed?

Answer (score 7):

Either create an alias to it in your shell, or put its directory ahead of the other in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to switch between them on the fly, without changing your `$PATH`, here's a little pattern I have used over the years, after seeing a coworker use this to good effect.  I assume you have a `$HOME/bin` already, really early in your `$PATH`. Create the following shell script there,

```
#/bin/sh
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" export PATH
exec ${1+"$@"}
```

called, for example "local".  Then you would invoke the version of svn in /usr/local/bin with the call:

```
$ local svn {whatever other arguments you need}
```

and just calling `svn` without this wrapper script will find whatever one is first on your `$PATH`.

Comment: I should add that this pattern is most useful if you have _two_ (or more) scripts: for example "stock" and "beta", or "sysv" and "bsd", or "gnu" and "stock".